# How many 3 digit integers are such that the sum of digits of integers is equal to 11?

Tags: combinatorics

I saw a problem of this kind sometime ago. It was solved using the coefficient of something in binomial theorem. I'm not sure. I am unable solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps these could get you started [Generating function to find the sum of digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762449/generating-function-to-find-the-sum-of-digits), [How many positive integers less than 1,000,000 have the sum of their digits equal to 19?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028849/how-many-positive-integers-less-than-1-000-000-have-the-sum-of-their-digits-equa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that we don't have our usual digits -- we still want to use base-10 notation, but have to write each *digit* by tally marks, with some spacer such as a colon between different powers of ten. So 123 would be written `I:II:III` and 307 would be written `III::IIIIIII`.

Now you're looking for 3-digit number -- so in our impoverished notation it contains two colons, and it doesn't start with a colon because then it would really be a 2-digit number. And the sum of the digits is eleven, so there are eleven `I`s.

In other words, what we're looking for is `I` followed by some combination of two colons and ten further `I`s. There are $\binom{12}{2}$ possibilities for this, but a few of them don't count, namely the ones where one of the digits is ten or more. But those are easy to enumerate: They are exactly `XI::` and `X:I:` and `X::I` and `I:X:` and `I::X`.

So subtract $5$ from $\binom{12}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve the following question:

How many two digit integers are there such that the sum of the digits is $k$, where $2\leq k\leq 10$? (Hint: after you choose the first digit, how many choices do you have for the second?)

Next, using the previous idea, how many 3 digit integers meeting your requirement are there that start with $1$? How about $2$? Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

Think of a three digit number as picking a number one through nine for the first digit, then any number zero through next two. So there are $9\cdot 10\cdot 10$ three digit numbers, and the number of these whose coefficients add to $11$ is the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in the expression

$$(x+x^2+\cdots+x^9)(1+x+\cdots+x^9)(1+x+\cdots+x^9).$$

To find this coefficient, you can ask a computer, or use the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). I got the answer 61.